# IIS URL Rewrite Stop Processing Enigma

Tags: url, iis, url-rewriting

What is the point of `stopProcessing="true"` being included by URL Rewrite for redirects - and in near every handwritten example on the Internet, when from what I understand, it only works for rewrites, or is it just because of bad UI design and near everyone just following the spit out without questioning?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the internals, and indeed `stopProcessing` doesn't make any sense for redirects and some other actions, just for `Rewrite` and `None`.

The IIS Manager GUI reflects this.

However the underlying XML schema for the Rewrite Module still has the `stopProcessing attribute for all rules regardless of the type.

The default for `stopProcessing` in the schema is `False`, so setting it to `True` makes it clear that there is no more processing of further rules after this one.

I think in reality it wouldn't make any difference if you set  `stopProcessing=False` for a redirect action, but I haven't tested this.